# x264 with multiple passes specify location of temporary file?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, x264, transcoding

So, my situation is like this. I have three x264 commands with 3 passes I want to run in parallel:

```
x264 -p 1 ...
x264 -p 1 ...
x264 -p 1 ...
```

Then I want to run the second pass in parallel:

```
x264 -p 2 ...
x264 -p 2 ...
x264 -p 2 ...
```

And the third pass as well.

The problem is, because I am running three x264 commands with -p option at the same time (using multiprocessing), they are all trying to use the same temporary files to save the results of the first/second pass.

Is there a way to specify for each x264 command to use a different temporary file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. I have used --stats option:

```
x264 -p 1 --stats file1.log ...
x264 -p 1 --stats file2.log ...
x264 -p 1 --stats file2.log ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the temporary files are created in the current directory, start the different instances from different directories. If they are all created in e.g. `/tmp`, using the same name more than once would be a bug, I'd say.